# How to Create a C Function with Array Input&Output

Tags: c

Dear C programming users, how to write a C programme with a C function which its input and output both array?

Specifically; I want to give two 4x4 matrix as input, then the function will multiply that two matrix, and give an output of the resultant matrix that is again in 4x4 matrix size? (Lets say: input is A and B, output is D.  A(4x4)*B(4x4)=D(4x4)  ).

I have found and written a main programme codes that can multiply two matrix. However I couldn't put that into a C function. I learned that C function only outputs a numeric value, but not an array or matrix.

How can I go around of that issue in C programming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is only 4x4 matrix by 4x4 matrix, in my case. I will use it as robot transformation matrix, and it is always 4x4 and square matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass both arrays into the function as pointers. This is easily achieved by just passing the name of the corresponding arrays.
As to the return 'value', you could certainly define your function to return a pointer to yet another array. But there is a problem there: 
Who owns that array?
In reality, you'll have two (three) viable options:

1) You declare the output array as a global variable. Not a good practice.

2) You declare the output array at the same place as both source arrays and pass the address of that output array as the third parameter to your function.

3) (Not recommended!) You could declare the output array as static within your function, and return a pointer to it.

PS: There are actually 2 other ways which I'll just mention, but don't let that confuse you.

1) You can actually pass whole arrays into functions by a little trick: You can put your array(s) into a structure. Structures DO get passed by value (with all their content). However, I personally find this inelegant and it also carries a performance penalty with it, as everything in the struct, including your arrays, has to be copied over the stack.

2) Your function could allocate the output array dynamically (using malloc or calloc) on the heap and return a pointer to that. However, this then leaves the caller of the function to later free() that memory again, and that is very easily overlooked. This would then create a memory leak. Also, heap allocations are quite expensive in terms of processing time.